# How to style SVG path to take an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

[Here is my JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3FP6P/24/)

I am simply trying to set up [this image](http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018712-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-shapes-circle.png)  in the middle of my arc. My best intuition tells to use .attr("fill","url('somePicture')"), but for the life of me that hasn't been a viable solution.

```
var width = 700,
    height = 600,
    tau = 2 * Math.PI

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(100)
            .outerRadius(250)
            .startAngle(0)

var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(0)
            .outerRadius(100)
            .startAngle(0)

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")")

//gray null background
var background = svg.append("path")
                    .datum({endAngle: tau})
                    .style("fill", "#ddd")
                    .attr("d", arc)

var center =     svg.append("image")
                    .append("path")
                    .datum({endAngle: tau})
                    .attr("d", arc2)
                    .attr("class","record")
                    .attr("xlink:href", "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define a path. If you look into your html, the image is there but it's of size 0x0.

```
var center =     svg.append("image")
                .datum({endAngle: tau})
                .attr("d", arc2)
                .attr("class","record")
                .attr("width",400)
                .attr("height",400)
                .attr("x",-200)
                .attr("y",-200)
                .attr("xlink:href", "http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018712-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-shapes-circle.png")
```

In your fiddle you attached the wrong image. If you keep your code the same aside from this it should work. Good luck.

Comment: ok thanks, that did work great. my only problem is getting the image to fit exactly to the size of the gap in the arc. is there a way to do this without hard-coding the size/position?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you mean that if you want to resize the whole thing, then the image will change with it. Correct? You can do that by making all numbers functions of others.

I start with defining

```
innerR = 100
```

for lack of a better name. Then all other non-zero functions are functions of that. There is a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3FP6P/25/). Experiment with that parameter and see what happens.

Comment: I recommend to you to use this as a general practice. That is, when parameters will depend on each other, to define them that way. It's not always obvious which ones they are but here for example all the radii will probably depend on each other because otherwise, changing one number will mess up the ratios.